# What is point in passing a function call expression into noexcept?

Tags: c++, exception, noexcept

What is the difference between this:

```
bool foo(int){return 0;}
void bar()noexcept(foo){}
```

And

```
void bar()noexcept(foo(10)){}
```

- In the first `bar` has the same exception specification as `foo` and the latter may throw so the two are equivalent to `noexcept(false)`. But what about the second version:

  `noexcept(noexcept(foo(10)))`?
- Are the two declarations identical?

Comment: Well, both should emit a compiler diagnostic since `foo` can't be implicitly converted to a `bool` and `foo(10)` isn't a literal expression (unless you mark `foo` as `constexpr`). Am I missing something? Did you mean to ask about `noexcept(noexcept(foo(10))` instead?

Comment: @Brian: I think it doesn't matter the return type or value here when it comes to be an expr passed to `noexcept`: `void f(double){}   void bar() noexcept(noexcept(f(.14))){}` will compile although `f(3.14)` returns `void`. Because it is not evaluated.

Comment: `noexcept(f(10))` and `noexcept(noexcept(f(10)))` are very different things

Comment: As far as `noexcept(foo)`... it doesn't do what you think it does by a country mile. All it does is convert `foo` to a bool. Function names always decay to valid addresses, so the extra bool conversion is always to `true`. That specification is a plain `noexcept` with extra steps.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Yes the first evaluates the expression and which must be constexpr but the latter no. I want to know what is the difference between: `noexcept(foo) and noexcept(noexcept(foo))`? I mean is the function call redundant here?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Would you add an answer to explain things a bit better? Thank you.

Comment: The later evaluates the constant expression alright. But the expression isn't `foo(10)`, it's `noexcept(foo(10))`. `noexcept` is an operator too, among other roles. `constexpr bool b = noxcept(f(10));` is a valid declaration.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica FWIW, that sort of conversion (function pointer to bool) isn't allowed in a [converted constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Converted_constant_expression), which the expression given to `noexcept` is.

Comment: @Brian - I'm not up to speed about the latest constraints of constant evalution. While it's true the [conv.bool] is only mentioned as part of integral conversion... this specific case seems possible to make permissible. Maybe a CWG issue I'm unaware of or some such. Dunno.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between this:
>
> ```
> bool foo(int){return 0;}
> void bar()noexcept(foo){}
> ```
>
> And
>
> ```
> void bar()noexcept(foo(10)){}
> ```

The difference isn't very important since both are ill-formed. But, let's look at why that is:

First is ill-formed because when `foo` is contextually convertd to `bool`, it will first implicitly convert to a pointer to function. Although the pointer is always going to point fo `foo` and thus the result is always true, such conversion is nevertheless not a constant expression and is thus not allowed in the `noexcept` specification.

Second is ill-formed because `foo` is not a constexpr function, so it may not be called in a `noexcept` specification.

---

> But what about the second version `noexcept(noexcept(foo(10)))`?

`noexcept(foo(10))` is false if the function invoked by the expression `foo(10)` is potentially throwing, and true if it is noexcept. Thus, this achieves the "copying" of the exception specification. Nearly always this is done when the expression in question is used within the function:

```
void bar() noexcept(noexcept(foo(10))) {
    bool example = foo(10);
}
```